# Archive / publish artifacts to a Samba share using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, samba

I found [the following plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin) that serves the purpose of publishing artifacts to a windows share (i.e., Samba) for "normal" Jenkins jobs.

But I couldn't find an equivalent for Jenkins Pipelines, something like

```
steps {
    publishOverCIFS('sambaServerCredentials', 'files', ...)
}
```

Does such a Pipeline DSL extension exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if there was no such plugin at the time of asking this question, it was developed as of now.

Link to plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-cifs

Documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-cifs/#publish-over-cifs

Excerpt from documentation:

```
cifsPublisher: Send build artifacts to a windows share
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the thing I was looking for back then :)